# Use of Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I want to get response from websites that take a simple input, which is also reflected in the parameter of the url. Is it better to simply get the result by using conventional methods, for example `OpenURI.open_uri(...)` with some parameter set, or it is better to use mechanize, extract the form, and get the result through submit?

The [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) page gives an example of extracting a form and submitting it to get the search result from Google search. However, this much can be done simply as `OpenURI.open_uri("http://www.google.com/search?q=...").read`. Is there any reason I should try to use one way or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of sites where it turns out to be easiest to use mechanize. If you need to log in, and set a cookie before accessing the data, then mechanize is a simple way of doing this. Similarly, if there are lots of hidden fields that need to be matched (such as CSRF token), then fetching the page using mechanize then submitting it with the data filled out is often a more foolproof method that crafting the URL yourself.

If it is a simple URI, like google's search pages, then manually constructing it may be simpler.